# Proving a theorem about weak convergence in $L^p$

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, lp-spaces

I want to show the following:

Let $(X,\mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measurable space. Consider $L^p(X,\mathcal{A}, \mu)$ where $1 <p < \infty$ and $q$ is the conjugate of $p$.
Further let $(f_n)_n$ be a sequence in $L^p(X,\mathcal{A}, \mu)$, that converges to $f \in L^p(X,\mathcal{A}, \mu)$. Show that for every $g \in L^q(X,\mathcal{A}, \mu)$

$\int_X f_ng d\mu \rightarrow \int_X fg d\mu$.

My attempt:
Since I have to show $\int_X f_ng \rightarrow \int_X fg$, let's consider

$|\int_X f_ng d\mu - \int_X fg d\mu|$

Thinking about how to get an estimate, I tought about the Hölder Inequality. Which states that for measurable $f$ and $g$ on $X$ such that $|f|< \infty$ and $|g| \infty$ almost everywhere on $X$ and $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$
we have
$||fg||_1 \leq ||f||_p||g||_q$
Thus I get $|\int_X f_ng d\mu - \int_X fg d\mu|\leq \int_X|f_ng-fg| d \mu=\int_X|g||f_n-f| d \mu$. Since $f_n,f \in L^p$, $L^p$ a vector space $\Rightarrow f_n-f \in L^p$. How applying the Hölder Inequality yields
$\int_X |g| |f_n-f| d \mu \leq ||g||_q ||f_n-f||_p$.
Now, since $||f_n-f||_p \rightarrow 0$, we get the result.

I have two questions. Is my solution correct? And does this hold for $p=1$ and $q=\infty$ too?

Comment: Are you unsure any step in particular? For the $p=1$ case, use the fact $g$ is essentially bounded by its $L^{\infty}$ norm.

Comment: Your solution is indeed correct and yes, the solution still holds for the $p = 1 \text{, } q = \infty$ case as well- it is easy to check that the inequality still holds in this case. Another way to prove this result would be to use the duality property $\Vert f \Vert_p = \sup_{g \in L^q, \Vert g \Vert_q = 1} \int f g d \mu.$

Comment: @FZan So I found that there is a Hölder Inequality ($||fg||_1 \leq ||f||_1 ||g||_{\infty}$) for the case $p=1, q=\infty$? Did you mean that with "$g $ is essentially bounded by its $L^{\infty}$ norm"?